# django model polymorphism with proxy inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-models, proxy-classes

My `Discount` model describes common fields for all types of discounts in the system. I have some proxy models which describe concrete algorithm for culculating total. Base `Discount` class has a member field named `type`, which is a string identifing its type and its related class.

```
class Discount(models.Model):
  TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('V', 'Value'),
    ('P', 'Percentage'),
  )

  name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
  code = models.CharField(max_length=32)
  quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
  type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.type:
      self.__class__ = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], self.type + 'Discount')
    super(Discount, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class ValueDiscount(Discount):
  class Meta:
    proxy = True

  def total(self, total):
    return total - self.value
```

But I keep getting exception of AttributeError saying self doesnt have type. How to fix this or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your init method needs to look like this instead:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Discount, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.type:
        self.__class__ = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], self.type + 'Discount')
```

You need to call super's `__init__` before you will be able to access `self.type`.

Becareful with calling your field `type` since `type` is also a python built-in function, though you might not run into any problems.

See: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type

Comment: Thank you. One more question, why do I need to call super __init__ before accessing objects properties? I thought that it's a python which makes all members declared in object accessable in constructor, not super class (models.Model from Django). How come?

Comment: This is because django.db.models.Model has `__metaclass__ = ModelBase`. This means that django uses `ModelBase` to create your Model class instead of the regular `type`. I highly suggest reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python - and once you've mastered metaclasses, look at the django source code.

Answer (score 1):

call `super(Discount, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` before referencing `self.type`.